# I Have 4-5 py file all of which uses same import libraries and Login using selenium python, Is their a better way for managing the import statement

Tags: python, selenium

Consider 3 file, a.py, b.py, c.py

a.py file

import time

import selenium

Login()

xyz

---

b.py file

import time

import selenium

Login()

abc,

---

c.py file

import time

import selenium

Login()

efg

---

what is the better way of managing the above file so that it should not repeat import statement and function.

Comment: There is not per se something wrong with repeating imports.  But it CAN be an indication of unnecessary code repetition.

Comment: This is not a concern: Python only reads and executes each imported file once per process. When executing an import for a module already present, it just binds the variable name in the current module.

Comment: The way you are doing it is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
# a.py
import time
import selenium

# b.py
from a import time, selenium #You can do like this...

# c.py
from b import * #...or like this
```

Anyway both the way of doing this are not recommended, you should better `import` al the needed modules at the beginning of your single files.

Comment: Thanks will try this and update

Comment: Dont' do this, this is very, very confusing

Comment: I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, you *really* shouldn't do this. I was just showing others way to do that. As I said "you should better import all the needed modules at the beginning of your single files".

Comment: Ok will continue doing the way I was thanks for the help

Comment: @SabaTaranum, if an answer worked for you you can accept it. Welcome to Stack Overflow anyways.